# Write to pipe deadlocking program

Tags: c, pipe

I am having a problem in my program that uses pipes.

What I am doing is using pipes along with fork/exec to send data to another process

What I have is something like this:

```
//pipes are created up here

if(fork() == 0) //child process
{
  ...
  execlp(...);
}
else
{
  ...
  fprintf(stderr, "Writing to pipe now\n");
  write(pipe, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
  fprintf(stderr, "Wrote to pipe!");
  ...
}
```

This works fine for most messages, but when the message is very large, the write into the pipe deadlocks.

I think the pipe might be full, but I do not know how to clear it.  I tried using fsync but that didn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close the read end of the pipe in the process doing the writing.  The OS will keep data written to the pipe in the pipe's buffer until *all* processes that have the read end of the pipe open actually read what's there.

Comment: This fixed it, thanks, I wasn't closing the pipe until after I finished writing to it